# Minimum bit program

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I am new in Java. I try to learn it from *Java Just in Time*.

Writer:

> So program to calculate how many bits would be needed to represent a given
>   number of different values.

And program is:

```
int numberOfValues = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int noOfBits = 0;

while (Math.pow(2, noOfBits) < numberOfValues)
  noOfBits = noOfBits + 1;
```

But book writer is ask to write this in other version.

Writer:

> In this task you will write a variation of the MinimumBitWidth program which works a little more efficiently. Instead of computing a power of 2 in the loop condition on each iteration, your version will accumulate 2 to the power of `noOfBits` in a separate variable. This can be done by initialising your new variable to `1`, and simply doubling its value each time you increment `noOfBits`.
>
> You will use the same test data as used for the previous version of the program.

Maybe because of weak English I don't understand what he means. Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Java is not the same as, or similar to, C++. Why did you use that tag?

Comment: i need algorithm not just solution.

Comment: What he means is don't recompute `Math.pow(2, noOfBits)` from scratch every time: save the value you computed in the previous loop, and update it to test in the next loop. Note that you can also use the `<<` operator to do simple powers of two not via floating-point numbers.

Comment: @Jongware "Java is not similar to C++": are you serious ?

Comment: `2^(noOfBits + 1) = 2 * 2^noOfBits`

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, he´s serious, and your code is nonsense. (Start with reading about XOR)

Comment: @deviantfan: these ^ denote exponentiation and this formula is the hint the the OP ismissing. His code snippet will compile equally well in Java and C++ and C# (except for the . :: scope resolution operator), with the same semantics.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Java and C# yes, C++ no. Just try it. pow with double and the unsigned thing are the first things which comes to mind. (not to mention the different Class/function names everywhere, not only one operator)

Answer (score 1):

It means compare the number with 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, ... 2<sup>31</sup>.
As 2<sup>31</sup> is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, one might use a long.

```
int noOfBits = 0;
long pow2 = 1;
while (numberOfValues >= pow2) {
    ++noOfBits;
    //pow2 = 2 * pow2
    //pow2 += pow2;
    //pow2 *= 2;
    pow2 <<= 1; // Shift left once.
}
```

See also [Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(int)), which would reduce the code to a one-liner.

```
int noOfBits = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(numberOfValues);
```